# How to count field in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

First of all, I am new to Crystal Reports so maybe what I am asking might say is stupid.

I added some tables and I want to count the appearance of a field depending on another field in the same table. If the other field has a certain value, I have to increase the counter. I have to use the returned value of the counter as a custom field in my report. I have to add multiple fields like this one, counting another thing. So...

How do I do this counting?

Thank you very much for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use running total field, evaluated by function (formula), which checks other field value.